# Excel Right Click Cell, Open File Path, Create Hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, hyperlink, right-click

I need to create hyperlinks to words in individual cells. Is there anyway I can right click on the cell and that directly opens "My Documents" folder and the file I click on creates a hyperlinks?

Comment: you can select the cell and Insert Hyperlink and choose the file

Comment: [Work with Hyperlink] <https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-hyperlinks-in-Excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e>

Comment: By doing so, I would have to click several folders to get my file. When you have dozens of cells to link, it becomes overwhelming. I need a right click that can take me directly to the folder I need.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `First Hyperlink` as usual:
Write the word in the cell
select the cell
`Insert Hyperlink` and choose **My Documents** then OK
Copy or Drag the cell with Hyperlink to other cells
Write the word you want and when you click on it, it will open **My Documents**
The Hyperlink is copied to the other cells even if you change the content (word)